# Call HTML Object inside the JScode

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sorry for the stupid header, but I really don't know how to name my question.

So basically, I have a number of functions in my code, one specific requires two divs to execute. So far everything works, but when I need to call the function inside a for-loop with a variable, I can't call it. To ask the question right, I'm gonna need you to look at some of the code. This is the Object, containing the Data.

```
var data = {
'coords' : [[784, 42], [802, 324], [128, 365], [710, 166], [610, 391], [513, 283], [544, 48], [323, 204], [316, 50], [938, 52]],
'walkthrough' : [8, 6, 0, 9, 3, 1, 5, 4, 7, 2],
'highscore' : 2283
};
```

That's the function to create the Objects in the right places, where I get my div1, div2 and so on.

```
(function(){

    for (var i = 0; i < data.coords.length; i += 1){
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.innerHTML = "<img src=\"Untitled-4.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"35\" height=\"35\" id=\"div" + i + "\">";
        span.style.position = "absolute";
        span.style.left = data.coords[i][0] + "px";
        span.style.top = data.coords[i][1] + "px";
        document.body.appendChild(span);
    }
}());
```

After another deal finishes I click a Button to execute this function

```
$(r).click(function() {

        for(var j = 0; j<data.walkthrough.length; j++){
                            connect(div[j], div[j+1], "#F0F", 3)
            }
        });
```

The problem is, I can't find out a way to write it so in the code, so that my JS understand which div it's about. I tried $("div" + data.walkthrough[j]) but didn't work. I can't leave the id's being just numbers, cause I won't be able to call another function, that I need.

Anyone has any idea, how to write the div[j] inside the for loop, so that it executes.(It has a JQuery inclueded.)

For the whole code -

http://jsfiddle.net/2dtxj/

If anything is unclear(which I fear will be the case, since I can't even understand myself sometimes :D) I'll answer questions about the questions itself.

Thanks in advance 
EDIT: the problem is, when I type connect(div1, div2, 'some_color', 5) works perfectly, but I can't figure out how to change the numbers according the to object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Ids are unique, this should work:

```
connect($('#div' + j).get(0), $('#div' + (j + 1)).get(0), "#F0F", 3);
```

if you are trying to pass the `connect-function` dom-objects.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot an `#` in front, so it's:

```
 $("#div" + data.walkthrough[j])
```

instead of:

```
 $("div" + data.walkthrough[j])
```

Comment: Yeah, I forgot it when I wrote the Question, but still somewhy it doesn't work